# How can I hide the word country in label while keeping Country invalid visible?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

If a user enters an invalid country, I want to change the text in label from country to Country invalid.

This is the html:

```
<div class="container">
                        <div id="js-white-country" class="white-country">
                            <label for="country">Country <span id="js-invalid-country" class="invalid-country">Country Invalid</span></label>
                            <input class="input country-input" placeholder="e.g. United States" id="country" type="text" />
                        </div>
                        <ul id='js-country-list' class="country-list">
                            <li id="US">United States</li>
                            <li id="AF">Afghanistan</li>
       </ul>
                        <button>explore</button>
                    </div>
```

This is my working jQuery:

```
function handleInvalidCountry() {
    $("#country").change("input", function () {
        $("#country").mouseleave(function () {
            let country = getId($("#country").val())
            if (country == "anError") {
                $('#js-white-country > label').text()
                $('#js-invalid-country').show()
            }
        })

    })

}

$(handleInvalidCountry());
```

this is the getId function:

```
countriesObject = {
    US: "United States",
    AF: "Afghanistan",
    AX: "Åland Islands",
}

function getId(country) {
    const keys = Object.keys(countriesObject);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (countriesObject[keys[i]].toLowerCase() === country.toLowerCase()) {
            return keys[i];
        }
    }
    return 'anError';
}
```

Edit: added function caller

Edit2: Seems like some people didn't get my question. My question is how can I hide the word 'country' in label and only show 'invalid country' when a user input is invalid.

Edit 3: The answers below are great and solved my issue in but all cases.
I'm using a function to populate the input element with a country when a user selects one from the dropdown. When a user does that, if they had entered an invalid country beforehand then then lable's text stays 'invalid county'. How can I solve this edge case? It seems to me that it's not considered an input.
Here the full code for readability:

```js
countriesObject = {
    US: "United States",
    AF: "Afghanistan",
    AX: "Åland Islands",
    AL: "Albania",
    DZ: "Algeria",
    AS: "American Samoa"
}


function filter(input) {
    const keys = Object.keys(countriesObject);
    let results = ``;
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (countriesObject[keys[i]].toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())) {
            results += `<li id="${keys[i]}">${countriesObject[keys[i]]}</li>`
        }
    }
    return results;
}

function getId(country) {
    const keys = Object.keys(countriesObject);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (countriesObject[keys[i]].toLowerCase() === country.toLowerCase() || 
        countriesObject[keys[i]].toLowerCase() === country.toLowerCase().trim()) {
            return keys[i];
        }
    }
    return 'anError';
}

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = new Array();
    container.push($('#js-country-list'));
    container.push($('#js-white-country'));

    $.each(container, function (key, value) {// the 'value' is each container item
        if (!$(value).is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && $(value).has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            $("#js-country-list").hide();
        }
    });
});

$("#country").on("input", function () {
    let country = getId($("#country").val())
    if ($("#country").val()) {
        if (country == "anError") {
            $('.invalid-country').text('Invalid Country')
        } else {
            $('.invalid-country').text('Country')
        }
    } else {
        $('.invalid-country').text('Country')
    }
})

function handleCountryClick() {
    $("#js-country-list").on("click", 'li', function () {
        $("#country").empty()
        $("#country").val($(this).text())
    })
}

//filter the content of the country list bast on current user input
function handleFilter() {
    $("#country").keyup(function () {
        let input = $('#country').val()
        $(`#js-country-list`).empty().append(filter(input))
    });
}


function handleCountries() {
    $('#js-country-list').hide();
    $('#country').click(function () {
        $("#js-country-list").show();
    });
    handleFilter()
    handleCountryClick()
}

function handleInvalidCountry() {
    $("#country").change("input", function () {
        console.log("hi")
        $("#country").mouseleave(function () {
            let country = getId($("#country").val())
            if (country == "anError") {
                $('#js-white-country > label').text()
                $('#js-invalid-country').show()
            }
        })

    })

}

function hideElements() {
    $('#js-invalid-country').hide()
    $('#js-results').hide();
    $('#js-no-news-message').hide();
}

function handleExploreApp() {
    hideElements()

    //set country list to hidden by default
    handleCountries()

};

$(handleExploreApp);
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div id="js-white-country" class="white-country">
                              <label for="country" class="invalid-country">Country</label>
                            <input class="input country-input" placeholder="e.g. United States" id="country" type="text" />
                        </div>
                        <ul id='js-country-list' class="country-list">
                            <li id="US">United States</li>
                            <li id="AF">Afghanistan</li>
                            <li id="AX">Åland Islands</li>
                            <li id="AL">Albania</li>
                            <li id="DZ">Algeria</li>
                            <li id="AS">American Samoa</li>
                                 </ul>
                        <button>explore</button>
                    </div>
 </div>          
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a video demonstrating the issue: https://youtu.be/UBF41x2_a-A

Comment: Span for the phrase 'Country invalid' is inside main 'Country' label. As you cannot hide parent label and show child span, ideally, change the text inside child span to just 'Invalid' and hide and show the same based on validity

Comment: I have updated my response; I hope the edit helps. Let me know if that doesn't meet your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use jQuery `.on` with `input` function and setting the label to display: none initially.

If you use `change` with `input` then you have to focus-out *means* click outside the input for the function to fun.

So ideally `.on` with `input` is what you need for better UX and validation.

If the typed word `matches` it will show the `invalid` label else it all `correct` it will hide automatically.

Run snippet below.

```js
$("#country").on("input", function() {
  let country = getId($("#country").val())
  if ($("#country").val()) {
    if (country == "anError") {
      $('.invalid-country').text('Invalid Country')
    } else {
      $('.invalid-country').text('Country')
    }
  } else {
    $('.invalid-country').text('Country')
  }
})


var countriesObject = {
  US: "United States",
  AF: "Afghanistan",
  AX: "Åland Islands",
}

function getId(country) {
  const keys = Object.keys(countriesObject);
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (countriesObject[keys[i]].toLowerCase() === country.toLowerCase()) {
      return keys[i];
    }
  }
  return 'anError';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="js-white-country" class="white-country">
    <label class="invalid-country">Country</label>
    <input class="input country-input" placeholder="e.g. United States" id="country" type="text" />
  </div>
  <ul id='js-country-list' class="country-list">
    <li id="US">United States</li>
    <li id="AF">Afghanistan</li>
  </ul>
  <button>explore</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution shows both, Country and invalid country. https://ibb.co/CBK2hT1

Comment: my question is how can i hide the word 'country' in label only show 'invalid country'

Comment: @E.Reiner I have edited the answer. Check  now all working.

Comment: keyup calls the function as soon as user starts typing in the field and "Invalid" is shown until full country name is entered. Is this what OP really wants? Does not look like a good UX to me

Comment: input behaves pretty much  same as keyup (but for keys that do not change the content) and which is better **change** or **input** would be the subject of a good debate, though off topic here :D

Answer (score 1):

Your functions aren't/weren't being called anywhere (or incorrectly); you're also using wrong event listeners (or unnecessary ones). Here is a working demo for you;

```js
countriesObject = {
    US: "United States",
    AF: "Afghanistan",
    AX: "Åland Islands",
}

function getId(country) {
    const keys = Object.keys(countriesObject);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (countriesObject[keys[i]].toLowerCase() === country.toLowerCase()) {
            return keys[i];
        }
    }
    return 'anError';
}

function handleInvalidCountry() {
   let country = getId($("#country").val())
   
   if (country == "anError" && $("#country").val()) {
       $('#js-white-country > label').text('Country Invalid');
   } else {
       $('#js-white-country > label').text('Country');
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="white-country" id="js-white-country">
        <label for="country">Country</label> <input class="input country-input" id="country" onchange="handleInvalidCountry();" placeholder="e.g. United States" type="text">
    </div>
    <ul class="country-list" id='js-country-list'>
        <li id="US">United States</li>
        <li id="AF">Afghanistan</li>
    </ul><button>explore</button>
</div>
```

Basically I modified your `handleInvalidCountry()` and had it call on `change` within the `input` field. I also removed the `span` as it wasn't necessary for what you're looking to do.

**EDIT:** Modified `handleInvalidCountry()` and some `HTML` to meet your updated/edited requirement.

Comment: This solution shows both, Country and invalid country .https://ibb.co/CBK2hT1

Comment: What do you mean by this? You will need to elaborate more in your question what you are trying to achieve. Please clarify or add more details.

Comment: Updated snippet. Should cover what you're looking for now?

Answer (score 1):

Look at my approach below and refer to these notes:

1. Instead of having `Country invalid` I have changed it to just `Invalid` which is shown or hidden upon validation. This simplifies your coding
2. First function is called on "change" of input field instead of "input", thus validation does not run on every key pressed
3. Inside `isCountryValid()` function, variable `countr` is assigned value `invalid` initially. Then `each` loop runs until it finds a match, and assigns the value to variable `countr`, that is returned by `isCountryValid()`. if no match was found, originally assigned `invalid` is returned
4. Based on the returned value from `isCountryValid()` you can change the visibility of `span` that has text `Invalid`

```js
countriesObject = {
            US: "United States",
            AF: "Afghanistan",
            AX: "Åland Islands",
        }

        function isCountryValid(country) {
            let countr = "invalid";
            $.each(countriesObject, function (k, v) {
                if (v.toLowerCase() === country.toLowerCase()) {
                    countr = v;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return countr;
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#country").change(function () {
                let country = isCountryValid($(this).val());
                if (country == "invalid") {
                    //$('#js-white-country > label').text();
                    $('#js-invalid-country').show();
                } else {
                    $('#js-invalid-country').hide();
                }
            })

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="js-white-country" class="white-country">
            <label for="country">Country <span id="js-invalid-country" class="invalid-country" style="display:none">Invalid</span></label>
            <input class="input country-input" placeholder="e.g. United States" id="country" type="text" />
        </div>
        <ul id='js-country-list' class="country-list">
            <li id="US">United States</li>
            <li id="AF">Afghanistan</li>
        </ul>
        <button>explore</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is not considered a good answer. Explain to the OP what have you done to fix it OR read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have added notes in the beginning explaining the flow of program